# Altium designer PCB error

Tags: pcb-design, altium, error

I am having an issue while updating my schematic in Altium PCB. There are two errors as shown in attached image. If anyone can please elaborate on how to solve these issues, I will be highly thankful..!!

[image]

Comment: Downvoted for straining my eyes.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure that for each component, the pin designators and the corresponding pad designators in their footprints are matching.

2) Update schematics with each symbol in schematic library.

3) Update PCB with imported changes from schematic.

Answer (score 0):

Could be that the pinout on the sch symbol and the footprint you linked it with do not get together.

Check the designators of the pins from the symbol and compare to the ones given to the footprint.

Comment: See the problem is with GND and other nets. The foot prints are correctly linked.

Comment: In order to check on the designators of your footprint simply open de PcbLib file where your footprint is stored and check on the designator names of each of the pads.

For the sch symbol, open the library of that symbol and double click on each pin. You will get information on the designator and name of the pin.

Then basically, the designator number on the pad of the footprint should match the one on the corresponding pin of the sch shymbol.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have different names of pins on footprint and schematic. 
For example: on footprint u have 2 pads with names 1 and 2. But on schematic - 'anode' and 'cathode'. And Altium cant bind anode->1 and cathode->2 (correct form is anode->anode or 1->1).
Check u footprint and/or schematic

Comment: can you please tell me how to change the names on footprints and component pins.

Comment: You symbol and footprint look like this (from off. site)

Comment: http://www.samacsys.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/08/altium13.png
and you can edit name of each pins on double click